# Filter a field in a form set (Django)

Tags: django, django-forms

How to filter a field on a form so that items created by another user are not ordered

I have a set of forms

```
from django import forms 
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory 
from .models import Course, Module 

ModuleFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Course, Module, 
                                      fields=['title', 'section', 'description'],
                                      extra=2,
                                      can_delete=True)
```

In the form in the list of sections, sections created by another teacher appear.

How to configure sections to be allocated only to the user who creates modules?

How to write a field filter on a form?

Comment: What are you looking to achieve precisely? Can't understand your request

Comment: Each teacher creates his own sections. When the form for saving the module is displayed in a drop-down form in all sections of the table. I need only sections of one teacher from whom the request is made to be ordered